# Vector space $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $W = W_1 \oplus W_2$.
Is it true that $\mathrm{Hom}(V, W_1) \oplus \mathrm{Hom}(V,W_2) = \mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$?

Is it true or false for any vector spaces? Could You copy a proof or counterexample?

Comment: Any ideas, thoughts, effort, work?

Comment: My idea is to try proof that exist non-zero $f \in Hom(V,W_1)$ and $f \in Hom(V,W_2)$. But i don't know if it's true and how to complete it.

Answer (score 4):

Literal equality is ***not*** true, but they are isomorphic via
$$\mathrm{Hom}(V,W_1)\oplus\mathrm{Hom}(V,W_2)\xrightarrow{\;\;\phi\;\;}\mathrm{Hom}(V,W_1\oplus W_2)$$
where $\phi$ sends the pair $(f,g)$ to the map $h\colon V\to W_1\oplus W_2$ defined by $h(v)=(f(v),g(v))$. It is not very hard to show that this is bijective, hence an isomorphism.

Comment: If equality isn't true, could you give an couterexample?

Comment: @JerryJohanson Do you know the difference between isomorphism and equality?

Comment: Vector spaces are isomorphic if exist isomorphism between them ie. R^3 and polynomials with degree <= 2. Isomorphism is some kind of linear function. Am I right?